# Can not print or show the keys of a dataframe but can save it to a csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a weird problem debugging a colleague's script

There is a panda's dataframe

when I try to print it `print(df)` or print their keys `print(df.keys())` I got

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 72-73: ordinal not in range(128)
```

but when I save it to a file `df.to_csv('a_file.csv')` I got a normal file.

Comment: Try: `df.to_csv('a_file.csv', encoding='latin1')`

Comment: `to_csv` does not present a problem. It is the printing that has the problem

Comment: Ok. And if you read again your output file and execute df.keys() do you still have the error?

Comment: In the csv file, are there any non-ascii characters? More specifically in the columns names?