# pandas concat does not respect the order of the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I don't know if this is related to [my previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76437849/can-not-print-or-show-the-keys-of-a-dataframe-but-can-save-it-to-a-csv) (and I did not want to put two problems in a single question) but I have two dataframes

(One of these can not be printed as the previous question states)

When I do

```
df= pd.concat([df_1, df_2])
```

the resulting dataframe has the keys in a totally wrong order (not like the keys of `df_1` and the keys o `df_2`). What could be happening?

Comment: How exactly do you expect people to actually answer your question without any way of reproducing the error you have?

Comment: Which pandas version did you use?

Comment: You have 2 weird problems. `pd.concat` does not sort columns by default. Please provide your version of Pandas. Do you have any emoticons in your columns/index?

Comment: @mozway I found out I am using pandas 0.22.0

Comment: Upgrade your version of Pandas. I think this is the same issue for your other question.

Comment: Yes, 0.22.0 is ancient, it's in pandas archeological times ;)

Comment: Don't you simply forget the `axis` parameter? `df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1)`?

Answer (score 1):

[`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) shouldn't sort the columns in recent versions:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=['A','D','C'])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]], columns=['E','B','F'])

out = pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1)
```

If you're using an older version, this might not be the case.

You can reorder with the column [`union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html):

```
pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1)[df_1.columns.union(df_2.columns, sort=False)]
```

Output:

```
   A  D  C   E   B   F
0  1  2  3   7   8   9
1  4  5  6  10  11  12
```

Answer (score 1):

`concat` does not simply stack one dataframe on top or next to other dataframe. You have to match the `key`. Especially if you stack them next to each other. Watch carefully the `index` otherwise you will get wrong result.

**Case A of stacking vertically:**

It matches same `column key` and add new columns if two dfs do not share the same name. Take an example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a', 'b'],
                    'val':[1,2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name2':['a', 'b', 'c'],
                    'val':[1,2,3]})

pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
```

This will give you

```
  name  val name2
0    a    1   NaN
1    b    2   NaN
0  NaN    1     a
1  NaN    2     b
2  NaN    3     c
```

**Case B of stacking next to each other:**

Given 3 dfs as follow:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a', 'b', 'c'],
                    'val':[1,2,3]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name2':['d', 'e', 'f'],
                    'val2':[4,5,6]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'name3':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
                    'val3':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
```

**Case B.1 normal and simple horizontal stacking:**

Everything is nice and clean right? Look on the next case `B.2` and `B.3`

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
  name  val name2  val2
0    a    1     d     4
1    b    2     e     5
2    c    3     f     6
```

**Case B.2 `index` discontinue**

For some reason, you manipulate the `df1`. In this case, you swap the two last rows

```
df1 = df1.reindex([0,2,1])
  name  val
0    a    1
2    c    3
1    b    2
```

If you concat with `df2` it will auto swap the rows of df2, and you get result different to the simple expectation that `concat` simply stacking next to each other

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
  name  val name2  val2
0    a    1     d     4
2    c    3     f     6
1    b    2     e     5
```

**Case B.3 `index` not the same**

This is an extension of case B.2 where you **forget** to `reset_index()` or `sort` and two dfs have total mess up `index`

```
df3 = df3.reindex([1,4,5])
  name3  val3
1     b     2
4     e     5
5     f     6
```

Now if you `concat`, here is the result:

```
pd.concat([df1, df3], axis=1)

  name  val name3  val3
0    a  1.0   NaN   NaN
1    b  2.0     b   2.0
2    c  3.0   NaN   NaN
4  NaN  NaN     e   5.0
5  NaN  NaN     f   6.0
```

**Conclude:** In my experience, before `concat`, simply run `df3.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`. Which avoid all unwanted issues later